# claims drafting

Tags: claims, drafting, wo2015002635a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2015002635A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2015002635A1)

Is it ok to write a word like ''substantially'' in claims?

Answer (score 2):

Words like "substantially" and "about" are heavily used in U.S. claims. A quick search of the USPTO's patent search database shows that close to 11% of all patents assigned to Apple, Inc., at issue, have "substantially" in a claim.  That includes 4 of the 31 utility patents issued to them July 31, 2018.

Yes, those words can come back to bite you, as can every single word in a claim. This is particularly true of claims written by someone inexperienced in the seeming illogical and often-changing art of claim drafting.

Please note that many such words are effectively banned from claims in some countries.

Answer (score 1):

In general words like "*substantially*" or "*approximately*" [should be avoided](https://www.ipwatchdog.com/2016/01/30/patent-drafting-relative-terminology-can-be-dangerous/id=65455/) in claims. That does not mean that the claims will be invalid automatically but it is an invitation for scrutiny.  As long a person having ordinary skill in the art would understand what substantially meant, it is acceptable. [MPEP 2173.02](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2173.html) provides the criteria for determining if a claim in definite.

However, if you are worried about protecting similar embodiments in an invention, the doctrine of equivalents (expalined below) should suffice and the word *substantially* is not necessary in the claims.

> The Doctrine of Equivalents is a test for infringement that if the product "*performs substantially the same task in substantially the same way to arrive at the same result*". See: [Graver Tank & Manufacturing Co. v. Linde Air Products Co., 339 U.S. 605 (1950)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graver_Tank_%26_Manufacturing_Co._v._Linde_Air_Products_Co.)

Comment: The doctrine of equivalents has been rarely recognized by courts in the last decade.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't rely on DOE, but I also wouldn't want to make my claims non-definite either.